# Facebook php SDK /me/feed posting link and not have the link go through the app, but straight to the page

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Built a custom app that will allow users to add jobs to a system. Once they've done that, it should post to their profile pages as well as their news feed. All of this is working perfect, except for one bit. If somebody else clicks on that link, let's say a friend of the person who has posted the link (from the system when adding a job) they're asked to install the app.

What should happen is a new tab should open with that position showing. If you use facebook like / recommend, this works, but requires the user to do it manually. When using the custom facebook app to do it via /user_id/feed, POST it shows the link and everything working fine, till one of their friends clicks on the link and is then requested to install the app.

How can I make so that the link being posted on the fan page, profile page of the user who has given permission to the app to do so, to just open in a new tab and go directly to the link that was posted instead of routing through the app?

Just to add on to this, the url that get's created via the app looks like this : http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=142332219213134&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=[the actual url being passed]&response_type=code&display=async&auth_referral=1

This makes that you HAVE to install the app to view the links... which should not happen, you should just be taken straight to the link that was shared via the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you probably have Authenticated Referrals enabled. I haven't worked with this feature but it sounds like it's related to your problem based on that URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals

Comment: Perfection! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!